# Keras Functional API Input shape Errors

Tags: api, keras, functional-programming, lstm, multiple-input

I am using Keras Functional API for a time series prediction with multivariate input and single output: `(x_1, x_2, y)`.
Therefore I have two network branches with several layers, that I concatenate after processing.

The code looks like this:

```py
# Define Model Input Sets
inputA = Input(shape=(4, 1))
inputB = Input(shape=(4, 1))

# Build Model Branch 1
branch_1 = layers.LSTM(8, activation='tanh', dropout=0.2, return_sequences=True)(inputA)
branch_1 = layers.Dense(8, activation='tanh')(branch_1)
branch_1 = layers.Dropout(0.2)(branch_1)
branch_1 = layers.LSTM(6, activation='tanh', dropout=0.2, return_sequences=True)(branch_1)
branch_1 = layers.Dense(6, activation='tanh')(branch_1)
branch_1 = layers.Dropout(0.2)(branch_1)
branch_1 = Model(inputs=inputA, outputs=branch_1) 

# Build Model Branch 2
branch_2 = layers.LSTM(8, activation='tanh', dropout=0.2, return_sequences=True)(inputB)
branch_2 = layers.Dense(8, activation='tanh')(branch_2)
branch_2 = layers.Dropout(0.2)(branch_2)
branch_2 = layers.LSTM(6, activation='tanh', dropout=0.2, return_sequences=True)(branch_2)
branch_2 = layers.Dense(6, activation='tanh')(branch_2)
branch_2 = layers.Dropout(0.2)(branch_2)
branch_2 = Model(inputs=inputB, outputs=branch_2) 

# Combine Model Branches
combined = layers.concatenate([branch_1.output, branch_2.output])

# apply a FC layer and then a regression prediction on the combined outputs
comb = layers.Dense(2, activation='tanh')(combined)
comb = layers.Dense(1, activation="linear")(comb)

# Accept the inputs of the two branches and then output a single value
model = Model(inputs=[branch_1.input, branch_2.input], outputs=comb)
model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Training
model.fit([x_1_train, x_2_train], y_train, epochs=ep, batch_size=bs)
```

Now, as the LSTM layer expects a 3D numpy array, I reshape my input data accordingly:

```py
# Data 
x_1 = data[['Temp']].values
x_2 = data[['Precip']].values
y = data[['GWL']].values

# Reshape Data
x_1 = np.reshape(x_1, (len(x_1), x_1.shape[1], 1)) # 3D tensor with shape (batch_size, timesteps, input_dim)
x_2 = np.reshape(x_2, (len(x_2), x_2.shape[1], 1))
y = np.reshape(y, (len(y), 1, 1))
```

Now my input data is of shape:

```
x_1: (4000, 4, 1)  
x_2: (4000, 4, 1)  
y: (4000, 1, 1)
```

as I also use a moving window/lookback of 4 timesteps on my input data.

And here is the problem. Because the moving `window/lookback` does not apply to my output, of course.

So I assume that's why I get this error when running the network:

> "Error when checking target: expected dense_6 to have shape (4, 1) but got array with shape (1, 1)
>   "

Because it works when I dont apply the moving window. But I need it, so I don't know what to do.

Can anyone help??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `model.summary()` to see the output shapes of your layers and model, and then adjust the model and/or the targets accordingly, the problem is that there is a mismatch between the output of the model and the targets.

For example, if you use an `LSTM` with `return_sequences=True`, then the output of that LSTM is 3D, which is fed into a `Dense` that only operates in the last dimension, also outputting a 3D shape. Maybe that is not what you want. You could just set `return_sequences=False` to the LSTM layers that are closer to the output, or just flatten if you really need them to output a sequence, so the `Dense` layers output 2D shapes, in which case you should reshape the targets as `(4000, 1)`.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the quick response. So setting the `return_sequence=False` and reshaping the target to `(4000, 1)` works. Or at least the model runs now. Im not sure what the flattening would do or why the `Dense` layer only operates in the last dimension and still outputs a 3D shape?  I would think it is better if the sequence gets passed on to the end??

Comment: @AaronOnStack If you don't need sequence output (more than one timestep), then using return sequences to False is fine. Also remember to upvote/accept if you are satisfied with the answer.

Comment: Ah ok, so as long as I have more than one time step, returning the sequence output is not necessary?

Comment: @AaronOnStack More than one timesteps requires a sequence, one timestep does not require a sequence.

Comment: Ah ok, so in that case I do need the sequence. My window size is my timesteps, so 4. Would I resolve that by flattening?

Comment: @AaronOnStack I am talking about the output sequence, not the input sequence.

Comment: Ok, so you mean as my output/ target is of `shape=4000,1,1`and therefore has one timestep, its ok to set `return_sequence=False`? Do I understand that correctly? And how would a Flattening of my input data be different to that?